# "Sort Lines" disabled in Sublime Text

Tags: sorting, sublime-text-3

I'm wondering why I can't click on `Edit > Sort Lines` in my Sublime Text 3 ?

[image]

I often use it and I don't think I've done anything which could disable it, so I don't know where to search...

What could disable this feature ?

Comment: Have you tried to select those lines and check if the sort option is available?

Comment: Yep, with or without selection, it's not available. Same if I use a saved file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me the reason was likely that *some dependencies of installed packages were missing*.

I **fixed** this using `Cmd+Shift+P` and finding (running) `Package Control: Satisfy Dependencies`.

I **restarted** Sublime Text after the operation and `Sort Lines` was again available for me.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `KeyboardSpellCheck` extension installed?  In my case this was the culprit. You may try removing it, to see if it fixes your problem.

1. Start Sublime Text
2. Enter Command Palette (using `Ctrl+Shift+P`)
3. Navigate to *Package Control: Remove Package*
4. Select KeyboardSpellCheck. This will uninstall the extension
5. Close and restart Sublime Text

Check is Edit / Sort Lines (F9) is back. If not, you may need to try removing other extensions, till you find the one that is causing the problem.

One way to start fresh is to delete everything from `Data/Installed Packages` and `Data/Packages` (save a copy first, obviously), and then add extensions one by one. That helps, if you have many extensions installed.